# image scraping from Social network like FB, Instagram, Twitter

Tags: laravel, web-scraping, web-applications, architecture, tagging

everyone.
Nice to meet you.
just now I am building a web application for artists and needed to scrape their images from FB, Instagram, Twitter, and personal websites.
if you have rich experience and in-depth knowledge about scraping, please help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/dusk)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to focus on is building web scrapers try using [Web Scraping Language](https://github.com/whatsdis/web-scraping-language)

```
CONFIG {'login': 'instagram.com'}
GOTO instagram.com
CRAWL //section/main/div/div/article/div/div/div/div
EXTRACT {'screenshot': '//section/main/div'}
```

What this does is login to instagram, click on each image, and take a screenshot of the photo because they hide the actual image url, `screenshot` lets you take photo of the element region.

However, it does appear that you really need some basic web scraping knowledge. You also need proxies to scrape these type of websites. You might be better off with having someone do it for you.